# Range of a parameterized surface function

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Here is a question from my textbook and I have to find out its domain and range.

$$\vec f(x,y)=(x+y , \frac{1}{y-1} , x^2+y^2) $$

I can get the correct domain but the answer of the range given by the book looks strange to me.

$$\text {{$(x,y,z) : y\neq 0 , y^2z=(xy-y-1)^2 + (y+1)^2$}}$$

I know $y$ cannot be zero but what does the last part of the answer mean ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer given in the book looks strange because it is expressed in the wrong variables. We have a vector-valued function
$${\bf f}:\quad (x,y)\mapsto\left\{
\eqalign{&u:=x+y \cr &v:={1\over y-1}\cr &w:=x^2+y^2\cr}\right.\tag{1}$$
and are supposed to give an implicit description of $S:={\rm range}({\bf f})$ in the form
$$S:=\{(u,v,w)\>|\>G(u,v,w)=0\}\ .$$
The variable $y$ in $(1)$ may take any value $\ne1$, and $v$ will then take any value $\ne0$. Since $x$ is completely free $u$ may take any value whatever the allowed $y$, resp., $v$. It follows that the set $S':=\pi(S)$, where $\pi$ denotes  vertical projection, is the  the full $(u,v)$-plane minus the line $v=0$.

Given a point $(u,v)\in S'$ there is a unique point $(x,y)\in{\rm dom}({\bf f})$ with ${\bf f}(x,y)=(u,v,w)$, and this point can be found by solving the first two equations of $(1)$ for $x$ and $y$. One obtains
$$x=u-1-{1\over v},\qquad y=1+{1\over v}\ .$$
The $w$-coordinate of ${\bf f}(x,y)$ is then given by
$$w=x^2+y^2=u^2-2u\left(1+{1\over v}\right)+2\left(1+{1\over v}\right)^2\ ,\tag{2}$$
and if $w$ has this value then $(u,v,w)\in S$. Since $v\ne0$ we may multiply $(2)$ by $v^2$ and see that the three variables $u$, $v$, $w$ are connected by the equation
$$wv^2=u^2v^2+2(v+1)(v+1-u)\ .\tag{3}$$
It follows that $S$ can be described as
$$S:=\{(u,v,w)\>|\>wv^2=u^2v^2+2(v+1)(v+1-u)\}\ .$$
It turns out that we don't have to list $v=0$ as an extra condition, since $(3)$ has no solutions with $v=0$.

Answer (score 1):

Look at it as a parametric equation.

$$x=u+v\\
y=\frac{1}{v-1}\\
z=u^2+v^2$$

$x,y,z$ satisfies the above conditions. Solving $v$ in terms of $y$, solving $u$ in terms of $x,y$, and plugging into the equation of $z$ will give you the desired range.